# PMA 4.5.2.0 file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, open-basedir

After installing phpMyAdmin on my Ubuntu server from PPA

https://launchpad.net/~nijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin

I get a series of warnings. Thanks in advance!

> Warning in ./libraries/Util.class.php#521 file_exists(): open_basedir
>   restriction in effect. File(doc/html/index.html) is not within the
>   allowed path(s):
>   (/tmp/:/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/)
>
> Backtrace
>
> ./libraries/Util.class.php#521: file_exists(string
>   'doc/html/index.html') ./libraries/sanitizing.lib.php#92:
>   PMA_Util::getDocuLink( string 'faq', string 'faq3-11', )
>   PMA_replaceDocLink(array) ./libraries/sanitizing.lib.php#152:
>   preg_replace_callback( string '/\[doc@([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\]/', string
>   'PMA_replaceDocLink', string 'Podría ser aproximado. Pulse en el
>   número para obtener la cantidad exacta. Ver [doc@faq3-11]FAQ
>   3.11.', ) ./templates/database/structure/table_header.phtml#43: PMA_sanitize(string 'Podría ser aproximado. Pulse en el número para
>   obtener la cantidad exacta. Ver [doc@faq3-11]FAQ 3.11[/doc].')
>   ./libraries/Template.class.php#80:
>   include(./templates/database/structure/table_header.phtml)
>   ./libraries/controllers/DatabaseStructureController.class.php#224:
>   PMA\Template->render(array) ./db_structure.php#54:
>   PMA\Controllers\DatabaseStructureController->indexAction()

Comment: You'd probably want to add your site's document root to the open_basedir allowed path...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forget it, I found the answer!

In my Ubuntu Server 14.04, I edited the file `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`, and searched for the following line:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/
```

And added `:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/` at the end and the warning went away!

Comment: Hmm, but this is already included in the package, so most likely you're using outdated version of the config file...

Comment: @ Michal | yes, usually when you create a backup file and move to a new server, to cut through with shortcuts old configs no longer work 100%

Comment: The main addition is this: **Please restart apache after any configurations to any config file.** I know this goes without saying but it cost me almost a day I'll never get back before I realized this. Goodluck