# Why does phpmyadmin give a file_exists warning?

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin is giving the following warning on the login page:

> Warning in ./libraries/Util.class.php#521  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(doc/html/index.html) is not within the allowed path(s): (/usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/)
>
> Backtrace ./libraries/Util.class.php#521: file_exists(string 'doc/html/index.html') ./libraries/Util.class.php#545: PMA_Util::getDocuLink( string 'index', string '', ) ./libraries/plugins/auth/AuthenticationCookie.class.php#175: PMA_Util::showDocu(string 'index') ./libraries/common.inc.php#880: AuthenticationCookie->auth() ./index.php#12: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

This [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212107/pma-4-5-2-0-file-exists-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect) `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` may not be configured correctly. I hence checked the `php_admin_value`:

> php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/php/php-gettext/:/usr/share/javascript/:/usr/share/php/tcpdf/:/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/

This looks right, so what am I missing?

Comment: What's the installation path of your phpmyadmin? PHP is trying to check if /doc/html/index.html exists relative to your phpmyadmin installation path. So that path must be in the open_basedir config value.

Comment: It's `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`. `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/doc/html/index.html` is there. Since it's specified above, that should be it, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was editing the wrong Apache configuration file. Instead of `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`, I should have been editing the one in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.